# Having issues running this code, I'm getting a .class error

Tags: java, for-loop, return-value

I'm having issues getting this to run.

I can't manage to get the return value to work properly. I'm a few weeks into this course and I'm learning a lot but this project has been a little bit of a struggle for me.

I'm collecting data, creating an average and then using that average to output the corresponding letter grade.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   import java.util.*;
    public class LetterGrade
    {
       public static void main(String args[]) 
       {
         calculateAvg();
         double avgScore;
         printLetter(double);


        }
        public static void calculateAvg()
           {      
              Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
              double avgScore; 

          for (double i = 0; i >0; i++) 
          {
              System.out.println("Enter your full name.");
              String name = console.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Enter test score 1");
              double score1 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Enter test score 2");
              double score2 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Enter test score 3");
              double score3 = console.nextDouble();

              avgScore = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
              avgScore = console.nextInt();

              System.out.printf( "%s, your average test score is: %.1f",name,avgScore);

                return avgScore;
              }
         }

            public static void printLetter(double avgScore)
            {
                    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
                    char grade;

                 if (avgScore >= 90)
                 {
                      grade = 'A';
                  }
                  else if (avgScore >= 80)
                  {
                     grade = 'B';
                  }
                  else if (avgScore >= 70)
                  {
                     grade = 'C';
                  }
                  else if (avgScore >= 60)
                  {
                     grade = 'D';
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     grade = 'F';
                 }

                    System.out.println("With that average, your grade is: " + grade);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made many mistakes.

In the main method you should save the calculated average into the variable and pass it to the `printLetter` method like this

```
double avgScore = calculateAvg();
printLetter(avgScore);
```

The `calculateAvg` method return type should be `double` so you have to declare it like this

```
public static double calculateAvg()
```

Also the for loop inside `calculateAvg` is wrong and unnecessary so just remove it. And assigning the `scanner.nextInt()` value to the `avgScore` will discard the properly calculated value. so the `calculateAvg` method should be like this

The `printLetter` method is correct but contains unnecessary lines like

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); //Could be removed
```

The resulting code is

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterGrade
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double avgScore = calculateAvg();
        printLetter(avgScore);
    }

    public static double calculateAvg()
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        double avgScore;

        System.out.println("Enter your full name.");
        String name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 1");
        double score1 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 2");
        double score2 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 3");
        double score3 = console.nextDouble();

        avgScore = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;

        System.out.printf( "%s, your average test score is: %.1f\n", name, avgScore);

        return avgScore;
    }

    public static void printLetter(double avgScore)
    {
        char grade;

        if (avgScore >= 90)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 80)
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 70)
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 60)
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        else
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }

        System.out.println("With that average, your grade is: " + grade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your program.

I have corrected the program with comments:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LetterGrade
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        double avgScore=  calculateAvg();
        printLetter(avgScore); //pass variable name here not datatype


    }
    public static double calculateAvg() //must have return type
    {      
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        double avgScore; 

        // for (double i = 0; i 0; i++) 
        //{
        System.out.println("Enter your full name.");
        String name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 1");
        double score1 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 2");
        double score2 = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter test score 3");
        double score3 = console.nextDouble();

        avgScore = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
        // avgScore = console.nextInt();

        System.out.printf( "%s, your average test score is: %.1f",name,avgScore);

        return avgScore;
        // }
    }

    public static void printLetter(double avgScore)
    {
        //Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        char grade;

        if (avgScore >= 90)
        {
            grade = 'A';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 80)
        {
            grade = 'B';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 70)
        {
            grade = 'C';
        }
        else if (avgScore >= 60)
        {
            grade = 'D';
        }
        else
        {
            grade = 'F';
        }

        System.out.println("With that average, your grade is: " + grade);

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
Enter your full name.
manisha
Enter test score 1
12
Enter test score 2
14
Enter test score 3
15
manisha, your average test score is: 13.7With that average, your grade is: F

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your `main` function. You have to assign the variable correctly to the return value of the `calculateAvg` method. Try this out:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    double avgScore = calculateAvg();
    printLetter(avgScore);

}
```

**Also notice:** double is the type of the variable, not the name. You have to give the name into the `printLetter()` method.

Another issue I just found is the doubled assigning of the `avgScore` variable which you have in your `calculateAvg()` method. Remove this line:

```
avgScore = console.nextInt();
```

This would force the user to again type in a value, which gets then assigned to the variable avgScore. This is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are some comments that I hope to be useful for you:
1- change the code in the main method to be like that 
         `double avgScore = calculateAvg();
         printLetter(avgScore);`
2- check the use of the for loop (maybe you need a do while loop)
3- remove the scanner in "printLetter" method
4- also as @NiklasLehnfeld suggest to remove `avgscore = console.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the main method to this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double avgScore = calculateAvg();
    printLetter(avgScore);
}
```